# HTML5 video not displaying on Safari but works on every other browser

Tags: javascript, css, html, video

The video and poster is displayed on Chrome, firefox and opera however not on safari despite the video being a .mp4 format..

https://brunelstudents.com/teambruneltest/

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). Although you have provided a [**link to an example or site**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it), if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

For safari you need to add **.webm** format video.

```
<video controls>
      <source src="somevideo.webm" type="video/webm">
      <source src="somevideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      I'm sorry; your browser doesn't support HTML5 video in WebM with VP8 or MP4 with H.264.
      <!-- You can embed a Flash player here, to play your mp4 video in older browsers -->
</video>
```